# Finding the supremum of a product of the difference between complex number of modulus one.

Tags: complex-numbers, supremum-and-infimum, products

I would like to have some help on the following problem:
Let $T=\{ z\in  \mathbb{C}~ |~|z|=1\}$ and $n\geq 2$ a positive integer. Find :

$$ \sup_{(z_{1},\cdots , z_{n}) \in T^{n}} (\Pi_{ 1 \leq j \neq k \leq n }  |z_{j}-z_{k}|)^{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}} $$

The progress I maid so far is the following :
Let $z_k=e^{2\pi ia_k}$.
$|z_j-z_k|=|e^{2\pi ia_j}-e^{2\pi ia_k}|=\\ =|\cos{(2\pi a_j)}-\cos{(2\pi a_k)}+i\sin{(2\pi a_j)}-i\sin{(2\pi a_k)}|=\\
=2|\sin{(\pi (a_j-a_k))}|$
$(\prod_{ 1 \leq j \neq k \leq n } |z_{j}-z_{k}|)^{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}}=\left(\prod_{1\leq j\neq k \leq n}2|\sin{(\pi (a_j-a_k))}|\right)^{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}}=\sqrt{2}\left(\prod |\sin{(\pi (a_j-a_k))}|\right)^{\frac{1}{n(n-1)}}$

Then I don't know how to continue. The maximum value of $x \to |\sin(x)|$ is $1$ so I need to find a combinaison of $a_{k}$  such that $|\sin(\pi (a_{j}-a_{k}))|=1$. I need $a_{j}-a_{k}$ to always be in the form $\frac{2m+1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $n$, we show that the required supremum $s_n=n^{\tfrac 1{n-1}}$.

Given any $(z_{1},\cdots , z_{n}) \in T^{n}$ let $Z=\| z_{ij}\|$ be an $n\times n$ [Vandermonde matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) such that $z_{ij}=z_j^{i-1}$ for each $i,j\in 1,\dots, n$. Then

$$\prod_{ 1 \leq j \neq k \leq n }  |z_{j}-z_{k}|=|\det Z|^2.$$

By [Hadamard's determinant bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Properties),
$|\det Z|\le n^{n/2}$. That is $s_n\le (n^{n})^{{\tfrac{1}{n(n-1)}}}=n^{\tfrac 1{n-1}}.$

On the other hand, put $\xi=e^{2\pi i/n}$ (here $i$ its the imaginary unit) and $z_i=\xi^{i-1}$ for each $i=1,\dots, n$. Then

$$|\det Z|^2=\left|\prod_{ 1 \leq j \neq k \leq n }  (z_{j}-z_{k})\right|=\left|\prod_{ 1 \leq j \neq k \leq n }  (\xi^{j-1}-\xi^{k-1})\right|=$$
$$\left|\prod_{ 1 \leq j \neq k \leq n }  (1-\xi^{k-j})\right|=\left|\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}  (1-\xi^m)^{n}\right|=|p(1)^n|,$$

where $p$ is a monic polynomial of $(n-1)$-th degree whose roots are $\xi^1,\dots, \xi^{n-1}$. That is $p(x)=\tfrac {x^{n}-1}{x-1}=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} x^m$. So $p(1)=n$  and $|\det Z|^2=n^n$, which follows $s_n\ge n^{\tfrac 1{n-1}}$.

Comment: Wow how could I come up with this, fantastic solution thanks Alex!